Error running PHP SOAP client with XAMPP: syntax error, unexpected

I'm having trouble running a PHP SOAP client with XAMPP. When I try to launch the PHP client I get a "syntax error, unexpected error followed by a wsdl file loading error.

    <wsdl:service name="UniversiteService">
        <wsdl:port name="UniversitePort" binding="tns:UniversiteBinding">
            <soap:address location="http//localhost/service/serveur.php" />
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>

code client soap
<?php

// Adresse du service web SOAP
$wsdl = '../service/uidtService.wsdl';

// Options pour la création du client SOAP
$options = array(
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE, // Pas de mise en cache du WSDL
    'trace' => true, // Permet de voir les requêtes SOAP envoyées
);

// Création du client SOAP
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);



try {
    // Appel de l'opération du service web SOAP pour récupérer les étudiants
    $responseEtudiants = $client->getEtudiant();

    // Affichage des étudiants récupérés
    echo "Liste des étudiants :\n";
    foreach ($responseEtudiants as $etudiant) {

        echo "Nom: {$studiant->nom}, 
        Prénom: {$etudiant->prenom}, 
        NIE: {$etudiant->nie}, 
        Date inscription: {$etudiant->date_inscription}\n";
    }

    // Appel de l'opération du service web SOAP pour récupérer les UFRs
    $responseUFRs = $client->getUFRs();

    // Affichage des UFRs récupérés
    echo "Liste des UFRs :\n";
    foreach ($responseUFRs as $ufr) {
        echo "Nom: {$ufr->nom_ufr}\n";
        // Ajoutez ici le code pour afficher les départements et les formations associées à chaque UFR
    }

    // Appel d'autres opérations du service web SOAP pour récupérer d'autres données
    // (départements, formations, etc.) et affichage des résultats de la même manière

} catch (SoapFault $e) {
    // Gestion des exceptions en cas d'erreur lors de l'appel du service web SOAP
    echo "Erreur : " . $e->getMessage();
}

error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>




I want to understand the problem linked to this url and how to fix it

What is the full and exact error message?

On which line do you get the error?

The syntax of the URL is incorrect. location="http//localhost/service/serveur.php" <-- the colon is missing.

Btw, if you want error reporting put it into the first line of code.

– Markus Zeller like this or location="http//localhost/..service/serveur.php"

No it's the colon which is missing. http// should be http://
